Existence of the limit of a function satisfying a condition similar to the Cauchy criterion
Suppose $f(x)$ is a function defined near $x=0$, satisfying
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(kx)-f(x)=0$$
for any $k\not=0$. Then can we prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ exists? Or can we find a counterexample?
It seems that if we only assume the condition holds for any $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, then a counterexample can be constructed as follows: divide $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ into equivalent classes by $x\sim y$ iff $ x/y\in\mathbb{Q}$. By the axiom of choice, we can define a function that is constant in each equivalent class. Then $f$ satisfies the condition for any $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ does not exist.

TL;DR
$f(x) = \sqrt{ \ln \frac{1}{|x|} }$ is a counterexample.
How to get there?
Using the assumption for $k = -1$ we can see that $f$ behaves equivalently to the left and to the right of zero. Hence we can reduce the scope of interest to the interval $\mathbb{R}_+ = (0, \infty)$ and $k > 0$.
Furthermore, we can replace the interval $(0, \infty)$ and multiplication with the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and addition using the standard substitution $(0, \infty) \ni x \mapsto \ln x \in \mathbb{R}$. Or better, $(0, \infty) \ni x \mapsto -\ln x \in \mathbb{R}$ just so that the limit endpoint $0$ of $(0, \infty)$ where the interesting stuff happens corresponds to $+\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $-\infty$.
The question thus becomes

Question'. If $g : [a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ (for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$) satisfies
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t + \alpha) - g(t) = 0 \qquad \text{for all } \alpha \in \mathbb{R},$$
does it follow that $g$ has a limit at $\infty$?

Since for any $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha > 0$
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t) = g(t_0) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big( g(t_0 + (n+1) \alpha) - g(t_0 + n \alpha) \big),$$
provided that the limit on the left exists, what naturally comes to mind is a divergent series with the general term approaching zero. For instance, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \big)$.
In a similar manner the function $g(t) = \sqrt{t}$ on $[0, \infty)$ is a counterexample to Question'. Now we change back to the initial variable and get $f(x) = g(-\ln x) = \sqrt{\ln \frac{1}{x}}$ as a counterexample to the multiplicative case on $(0, \infty)$. It remains to reflect the function symmetrically (by replacing $x$ with $|x|$) to get a counterexample on a neighborhood of zero.
Bonus: we could also take $g(t) = \sin \sqrt{t}$ (and go back with the substitution) to get a bounded counterexample.

With stronger assumptions
If we assume that for each $\alpha \geqslant 0$ there is $C > 0$ such that $|g(t+\alpha)-g(t)| \leqslant C e^{-t}$ for sufficiently large $t$, then the conclusion becomes true.
Proof. Take a large $N$ and $C$ such that
$$\tag{1} |g(t+1)-g(t)| \leqslant C e^{-t} \qquad \text{for } t \geqslant N.$$
Fix $t \geqslant N$ and take $M$ and $C_2$ such that
$$\tag{2} |g(s+t-N)-g(s)| \leqslant C_2 e^{-s} \qquad \text{for } s \geqslant M.$$
Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N+n \geqslant M$ and $C_2 e^{-n} \leqslant C$, put $\gamma = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{e}}$. Then
$$\begin{align*} |g(N) - g(N+n)| & \overset{(1)}{\leqslant} C \gamma e^{-N} \\[1ex] |g(N+n) - g(t+n)| & \overset{(2)}{\leqslant} C_2 e^{-N-n} \\[1ex] |g(t+n) - g(t)| & \overset{(1)}{\leqslant} C \gamma e^{-t} \end{align*}$$
and so $|g(N) - g(t)| \leqslant 3 C \gamma e^{-N}$ for $t \geqslant N$ and the RHS can be made arbitrarily small. It follows that $g(t)$ satisfies the Cauchy condition at $\infty$, so it has a limit.

A more interesting variant of the question that avoids the "divergent sum of terms approaching zero" phenomenon would be to assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(k^n x)$ exists for every $x$ and $k \in (0, 1)$, and does not depend on these parameters. Or since it's just easier to think additively, and since the value of the limit is irrelevant, we can just assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(t+n \alpha) = 0$ for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha > 0$ and ask if $\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t)$ must exist.

Thanks! Your answer is really enlightening. What if I strengthen the condition to $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{t}(g(t+\alpha)-g(t))$ exists?

@Holomodric Then it becomes true, see the updated answer.

But I don't assume $e^{t}(g(t+\alpha)-g(t))$ are uniformly bounded

@Holomodric For each $\alpha > 0$ you assume that $e^t \big( g(t+\alpha) - g(t) \big)$ approches zero. In particular, its absolute value becomes $\leqslant 1$ for sufficiently large $t$. So your assumption implies mine, right? I only used the assumption for $\alpha = 1$ and later for $\alpha = t-N$ where $t$ and $N$ were already fixed, so I don't believe I used any sort of uniform boundedness with respect to $\alpha$.

My assumption is $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{t}(g(t+\alpha)-g(t))$ exists, not $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{t}(g(t+\alpha)-g(t))=0$

@Holomodric Aw you're right, I totally imagined that it must equal zero. Fortunately that changes very little: if $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^t \big( g(t+\alpha) - g(t) \big) = c$ (depending on $\alpha$), then $|g(t+\alpha) - g(t)| \leqslant (|c|+1) e^{-t} = C e^{-t}$ for sufficiently large $t$ and the rest goes through with $C$ instead of $1$.

Thanks! I think your proof is completely correct. Besides, I think we can also note that the stronger assumption implies that $\lim_{t\rightarrow}e^{t/2}(g(t+\alpha)-g(t))=0$ and apply your previous argument, right?

@Holomodric Yeah, that works too.
